# How to show (graphically) transitive relationships in neo4j without altering the data

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say my data include nodes of the type `Person`, `Company` and `Country`.
A person `WORKS_AT` a company and a company `IS_IN` a country.

```
CREATE (Person {name:"Paul"});
CREATE (Company {brand:"BG"});
CREATE (Country {code:"UK"});

MATCH (person {name:"Paul"}),(company {brand:"BG"}) CREATE (person)-[worksat:WORKS_AT]->(company) return person,worksat,company
MATCH (company {brand:"BG"}),(country {code:"UK"}) CREATE (company)-[isin:IS_IN]->(country) return company,isin,country
```

So what i want is to be able to see the `person->country` data in a visual graph way, in the neo4j default browser, bypassing completely the `company` node in between (which should not be visible). 
But without creating a direct permanent relationship between the Person node and the Country node.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The browser does not have support for this. You will either need to use another framework to visualize your data, or you will need to create a unique "TEMP" relationship, and then run `MATCH ()-[r:TEMP]->() DELETE r` when you are done. Although, in this case `RETURN COLLECT(person) as people, county` is probably much easier. (You won't get the graph, but I think the table you will get will be easy enough to parse by glance)

Answer (score 1):

You can use virtual relationships in the graphical result using [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_virtual) (these are not saved to your graph data).

Here's how this would work, provided that the nodes are labeled accordingly (your above creation queries aren't adding labels, so definitely fix that):

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:WORKS_AT]->()-[:IS_IN]->(c:Country)
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(p,'WORKS_IN',{},c) yield rel
RETURN p, rel, c
```